# Unable to get table headings in IMPORTXML Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
`# <response>
#  <errorno/>
#   <rowcount>2</rowcount>
#   <rows>
# 
# <resource>
#   <Branch_ID>ABC<Branch_ID/>
#   <area_id>1234</area_id>
#   <Dealer_id>6802</Dealer_id>
# </resource>
# 
# <resource>
#   <Branch_ID>DEF</Branch_ID>
#   <area_id>5678</area_id>
#   <Dealer_ID>9999</Dealer_ID>
# </resource>
# 
#   </rows>
#  <error/>
# </response>`
```

This is the data I want to parse. I want the output to be in tabular form with headings as Branch_ID, area_id and Dealer_id with data from each resource tag.

I tried: =IMPORTXML(info!A2,"//rows//resource")
But I am not getting the table headings. info!a2 is the source URL of this XML

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `<resource>` tags. After the selection stage, Sheets is apparently taking it upon itself to process each matching block into a spreadsheet row, and each child tag of any type into a cell in said row.

I don't believe xpath functions like [`name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name), which return raw strings, can thusly be accessed by Sheets.

In any other context, I'd suggest a path that [evaluates](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to the resource tags' children's names and text contents

```
//rows//resource[1]/*/name(), //rows//resource/*/text()
```

but without parent and child xml tags intact, I'm afraid Sheets is not up to the task of parsing it.

Comment: I'd love to be wrong about this one. Anyone with anything to add, please answer or comment! I was nerd-sniped into trying to construct an xpath for preserving tags to wrap around the name() results, etc. but it's beyond me.